# Something Wrong With My Pex Permissions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

http://pastebin.com/XduW37C2
Keep getting an error that something is wrong. Can someone identify the problem?

Comment: You need to add more information to this question, error messages, screenshots etc. There are many things that can go 'wrong' when configuring a Minecraft/Bukkit server. We can only help when you give enough data. Also, you example does not appear to include permissions inheritance which is needed for ranks to work smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

PEX uses YAML (short for YAML Ain't Markup Language) for it's configs, which does not allow tabs and requires the use of spaces for indentation instead. Your config has a tab at the end of line 140, which causes a parsing error, remove it and it should load fine.